# Create Table query is not working in sqlite xcode.

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

```
NSString *sql_stmt_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:

@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MOBILE (TABLENAME TEXT ,FIRST TEXT , 
                                     SECOND TEXT , THIRD TEXT , 
                                     FOURTH TEXT , FIFTH TEXT)"];

const char *sql_stmt = [sql_stmt_string UTF8String];

if(sqlite3_exec(db ,sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK)

{
     NSLog(@" Table not Created");

    sqlite3_close(db);        

} else

{
    NSLog(@" Table Created");
}
```

Comment: Define `not working` properly

Comment: The console shows me that " Table is not Created". Why .??

Comment: @AlvinVarghese did you open database before create table??

Comment: Query statement is fine but this line `if(sqlite3_exec(db ,sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK)` is error prone

Comment: @AlvinVarghese reply me did u import database file to your project and opened database before creating table??

Comment: i did those two and then tried your code and it is working fine.

Comment: @AlvinVarghese: If `sqlite3_exec()` fails then `err` is set to an error message. What is the error?

Comment: yes. I opened the database. Log- "Database Opened"

Comment: When an error occurs, you should call [sqlite3_errmsg](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html).

Comment: My guess is that you are not copying the database to your writable directory before you try to use it.  You can't write to things inside your app's bundle.

Comment: @AlvinVarghese did you try my code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to open connection to the database. what you should do is like

```
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
if(sqlite3_exec(db ,sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK)
}
```

NOTE: don't stress on syntax. I have very less or no idea about SQLITE/Objective-C. This is just to show you an example and let you know where you went wrong (OR) the issue is.

Comment: i already opened the database in my .h file. And i put the create table inside of an another function. When i add the database opening code to starting of function its all work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it is working for me.

```
 if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK)
 {
     NSString *sql_stmt_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MOBILE (TABLENAME TEXT ,FIRST TEXT ,SECOND TEXT , THIRD TEXT ,FOURTH TEXT , FIFTH TEXT)"];


     const char *sql_stmt = [sql_stmt_string UTF8String];
     if(sqlite3_exec(db ,sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
     {
         NSLog(@" Table not Created");

         // sqlite3_close(db);

     } else

     {
         NSLog(@" Table Created");
     }
 }
```

Comment: That might work in the Simulator, but it will not work on the device because the application bundle is *read-only*.